# Draw on Custom Image view

Tags: android, canvas, view, imageview

I am working on Image Editor that allow the user to choose an image from the gallery and then draw objects on the image.

I created a custom ImageView and called setImageBitmap with the chosen image.

The problem is that the image is placed in the center of the screen and when I try to draw say a rectangle form (0, 0) to (100, 100), it is drawn starting from the left top corner of the screen not the image.

Also, the width and the height of the chosen bitmap are different from the width and the height of the canvas in onDraw() method in the custom ImageView.How is that ?

Comment: set attributes  android:scaleType="fitXY",android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: I don't want to scale the image and I need a way to draw on the image directly wherever it is (center or top).

Answer (score 0):

After choosing the image, make bitmap of selected image and try below code:

```
int currentBitmapWidth = bitMap.getWidth();
int currentBitmapHeight = bitMap.getHeight();

int ivWidth = imageView.getWidth();
int ivHeight = imageView.getHeight();
int newWidth = ivWidth;

newHeight = (int) Math.floor((double) currentBitmapHeight *( (double) 
new_width / (double) currentBitmapWidth));

Bitmap newbitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitMap, newWidth, 
newHeight, true);

imageView.setImageBitmap(newbitMap)
```

This will set the image to the size of your imageView.